# How can I make the CASE statement print only the values that meet the condition?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that calculates a payroll for me. Currently, the code can determine the days worked, years of seniority, and based on the years of seniority, multiply the salary and show what would be given additionally for seniority. What I want to know is why the code generates several results when I only need those that are not Null in the `AdditionalPerSeniority` column.

[What I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f2tU.png)

Whole code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalcularDiasTrabajo]
    @FechaInicio DATE,
    @FechaFin DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DiasDelMes INT

    SET @DiasDelMes = 30
    DECLARE @TotalDiasTrabajados INT

    IF (MONTH(@FechaInicio) = 2 AND MONTH(@FechaFin) = 2 ) 
    BEGIN---Primer if---
        IF(DATEDIFF(day, @FechaInicio, @FechaFin)+1=28 OR DATEDIFF(day, @FechaInicio, @FechaFin)+1=29)---Si esta en febrero + los dias ingresados resultan a 28---
        BEGIN
            SET @TotalDiasTrabajados = 30

            SELECT 
                e.IdEmpleado, e.Nombres, e.Apellidos, 
                s.TipoContrato, s.Salario,
                ROUND(s.Salario / @DiasDelMes,2) AS SalarioDiario, 
                @TotalDiasTrabajados AS TotalDiasTrabajados,
                ROUND(@TotalDiasTrabajados * (s.Salario / @DiasDelMes),2) AS SalarioCalculado
            FROM 
                contratacion.Empleados e
            INNER JOIN 
                contratacion.Contrato s ON e.IdEmpleado = s.IdEmpleado
            WHERE 
                s.FechaInicio <= @FechaFin AND s.FechaFin >= @FechaInicio;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @TotalDiasTrabajados = DATEDIFF(day, @FechaInicio, @FechaFin)+1

            SELECT 
                e.IdEmpleado, e.Nombres, e.Apellidos, 
                s.TipoContrato, s.Salario,
                ROUND(s.Salario / @DiasDelMes,2) AS SalarioDiario, 
                @TotalDiasTrabajados AS TotalDiasTrabajados,
                ROUND(@TotalDiasTrabajados * (s.Salario / @DiasDelMes),2) AS SalarioCalculado
            FROM 
                contratacion.Empleados e
            INNER JOIN 
                contratacion.Contrato s ON e.IdEmpleado = s.IdEmpleado
            WHERE 
                s.FechaInicio <= @FechaFin AND s.FechaFin >= @FechaInicio;
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN---En caso que no sea febrero---
        SET @TotalDiasTrabajados = DATEDIFF(day, @FechaInicio, @FechaFin)+1
        ---Seccion de cosas a hacer---
        SELECT e.IdEmpleado, e.Nombres, e.Apellidos, s.TipoContrato, s.Salario,
            ROUND(s.Salario / @DiasDelMes,2) AS SalarioDiario,
            DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) AS Antiguedad,
            @TotalDiasTrabajados AS TotalDiasTrabajados,
            ROUND(@TotalDiasTrabajados * (s.Salario / @DiasDelMes),2) AS SalarioCalculado,

            CASE
            ---problema aqui---
            WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) = pa.AñosAntiguedad 
                AND pa.AñosAntiguedad = DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin)
                THEN ROUND((s.Salario * pa.Porcentaje), 2)
            END AS AdicionalPorAntiguedad

            ---Seccion de cosas a hacer---
        FROM contratacion.Empleados e
        INNER JOIN contratacion.Contrato s ON e.IdEmpleado = s.IdEmpleado
        LEFT JOIN  contratacion.PorcentajeAntiguedad pa ON DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) >= pa.AñosAntiguedad
        WHERE s.FechaInicio <= @FechaFin AND (s.FechaFin IS NULL OR s.FechaFin >= @FechaInicio)
        GROUP BY e.IdEmpleado, e.Nombres, e.Apellidos, s.TipoContrato, s.Salario, s.FechaInicio, pa.AñosAntiguedad, pa.Porcentaje
    END
END
```

I would like it to not generate the other rows with null records. I tried to solve it with a `GROUP BY` after the general query, but in the end, the problem remains the same because I don't need it to generate that data. It's like it's going through the seniority table and generating a row for each one of the cases.

I'm specifically working with this section of the code:

```
        SET @TotalDiasTrabajados = DATEDIFF(day, @FechaInicio, @FechaFin)+1
    ---Seccion de cosas a hacer---
    SELECT e.IdEmpleado, e.Nombres, e.Apellidos, s.TipoContrato, s.Salario,
        ROUND(s.Salario / @DiasDelMes,2) AS SalarioDiario,
        DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) AS Antiguedad,
        @TotalDiasTrabajados AS TotalDiasTrabajados,
        ROUND(@TotalDiasTrabajados * (s.Salario / @DiasDelMes),2) AS SalarioCalculado,

        CASE
        ---problema aqui---
        WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) = pa.AñosAntiguedad 
            AND pa.AñosAntiguedad = DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin)
            THEN ROUND((s.Salario * pa.Porcentaje), 2)
        END AS AdicionalPorAntiguedad

        ---Seccion de cosas a hacer---
    FROM contratacion.Empleados e
    INNER JOIN contratacion.Contrato s ON e.IdEmpleado = s.IdEmpleado
    LEFT JOIN  contratacion.PorcentajeAntiguedad pa ON DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) >= pa.AñosAntiguedad
    WHERE s.FechaInicio <= @FechaFin AND (s.FechaFin IS NULL OR s.FechaFin >= @FechaInicio)
    GROUP BY e.IdEmpleado, e.Nombres, e.Apellidos, s.TipoContrato, s.Salario, s.FechaInicio, pa.AñosAntiguedad, pa.Porcentaje
```

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

The keyword 'DISTINCT' is used to remove or ignore duplicate records.

For Example:

```
select id, sum(distinct y) as sum_unique,
       coalesce(sum(distinct case when x < 30 then y end),0) +
          coalesce(sum(case when x >= 30 then y end),0) as sum_unique_criteria
from temp
group by 1;
```

OR
`CASE WHEN (ID IS NULL) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS ID_Value,`

so use `Distinct` to remove duplicates and to avoid null entries in case use case statement like `case column_name IS NOT NULL......`

Comment: Thank's , It did help to reduce the number of times the same Employee got printed out in the case statement , It reduced the number of times something was printed from 5 entries to just 2 , however The CASE statement still prints out 1 null value

Comment: Please check if my edit didn't split into separate code snippets what was intended as one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that the left join was set to:

`LEFT JOIN  contratacion.PorcentajeAntiguedad pa ON DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin)`  **`>=`** `pa.AñosAntiguedad`

when it should have been:
`LEFT JOIN  contratacion.PorcentajeAntiguedad pa ON DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin)`  **`=`** `pa.AñosAntiguedad`